# How to use html tags in <pre> when updated from the script

Tags: javascript, html, pre

I have a text `<pre id="printed-table">bunch of monkeys</pre>`. I want to process the text with a javascript `window.onload` to highlight the word `monkeys`.

So, it should look like

```
bunch of monkeys
```

when page is loaded.

I have a script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var p = document.getElementById("printed-table");
    var t = p.firstChild.nodeValue;
    p.firstChild.nodeValue = t.replace(/monkeys/gmi, function(a) {
return "<strong>" + a + "</strong>"; } ) } 
</script>
```

But when the page loads it looks like

```
bunch of &lt;strong&gt;monkeys&lt;/strong&gt;
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `p.innerHTML` instead of `p.firstChild.nodeValue`. If you do, you'll set the actual HTML contents of the element instead of the (text) value of the text node inside the `<pre>` element.

```js
  window.onload = function() {
    var p = document.getElementById("printed-table");
    var t = p.firstChild.nodeValue;
    p.innerHTML = t.replace(/monkeys/gmi, function(a) {
      return "<strong>" + a + "</strong>"; } ) }
```

```html
 <pre id="printed-table">bunch of monkeys</pre>
```